# PostgreSQL - Deleting data that are older than an hour, and then inserting new data to the same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wrote a function called `insert_offset_data(text, double precision)` as the following:

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO tempoffset(id, location, offset_factor, ts_insert) 
VALUES (uuid_generate_v4(), location_in, offset_in, (now() at time zone 'utc'));

RETURN 1;
END;
```

However, since this function is used in an API call whenever users insert data from an iOS application, I would love to delete data that are older than 1 hour in the table before inserting new data to it since the iOS application doesn't take into account data that are older than an hour. How do I write code to delete old data before I insert a new data in the same function?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add this:

```
DELETE FROM tempoffset WHERE ts_insert < now()-'1 hour'::interval;
```

Comment: This is correct way to do for PostgreSQL as per 2022. This saved me hours of searching around. Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You can pull out the data using a where statement, e.g. select rows where date is > current time - 1 hour.

You can also set a daily cron job to delete from the table where values are less than a certain value.