# How do i delete data from database except last 24 hour UNIX Time Format

Tags: php, mysql

I want to delete data from database via corn.

For example: i need to delete my all data except last 24 hour.

My time format is UNIX time
Like

> 1531920800

Comment: Maybe this helps you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25650658/postgresql-deleting-data-that-are-older-than-an-hour-and-then-inserting-new-d

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code? Please, take the [tour].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL - Deleting data that are older than an hour, and then inserting new data to the same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25650658/postgresql-deleting-data-that-are-older-than-an-hour-and-then-inserting-new-d)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$time = time();
$oneDay = 60 * 60 * 24;
$yesterday = $time - $oneDay;

$sql = 'DELETE FROM tablename WHERE columname < ' . $yesterday;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` to access the current time since the UNIX epoch, then adjust it backwards by 24 hours.  Something like this:

```
DELETE FROM yourTable
WHERE ts_column < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (24*60*60);
```

Comment: `$sql = "DELETE FROM leads WHERE udate < UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (24*60*60) AND fstatus=3";
` IS this right bro ??

Comment: @AshikKaiser Assuming that restriction on `fstatus` is what you want, then yes, your query looks correct to me.

Comment: Its others colume name .